# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

im running it in the vs code terminal
do check the error

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send("hello world");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("running on port 3000 ");
})
```

Comment: everything is working fine.what error do you get ?

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: is this all your code?

Comment: in which line you are getting this error?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error?

Comment: C:\chatbot\myapp>node sample_exp.js
C:\chatbot\myapp\sample_exp.js:10
app.listen(3000
           ^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)←[39m

Answer (score 1):

you should change your code to this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send("hello world");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("running on port 3000 ");
})
```

or update you node version for compile arrow function in node js

Comment: C:\chatbot\myapp>node sample_exp.js C:\chatbot\myapp\sample_exp.js:10 app.listen(3000 ^^^^ SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list ←[90m at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)←[39m ←[90m at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)←[39m ←[90m at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)←[39m ←[90m at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)←[39m –

Comment: I think this is not all of your code, and you might find it difficult to load some of the modules you used, and node js can't load them. Also read this link : https://airbrake.io/blog/javascript-error-handling/syntaxerror-missing-after-argument-list